# \n newline character won't work with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to put different information in separate lines, I have a working Javascript library, but I can't force the text output to display a newline.  Here is the relevant part of the Javascript:

```
var information = layer.objectAdd({
            type:"tooltip", 
            clickable: true,
            Title: "My title", 
            Description: "My description1 \nMy description2"});
```

Here is the desired output:

```
My description1
My description2
```

And here is what I get:

```
My description1 My description2
```

Why is this, I mean is there another way to jump to a newline?

Sorry if I missled someone, I have a Javascript library for generating tooltips.  I cannot change it because it's not my decision to make.  I need to make it work, and I can't use any HTML tags because I will get it printed out because it's not being rendered in HTML. Like, I just tried

```
Description: "My description1 <br /> My description2"});
```

And it just printed `My description1 <br /> My description2`.  Same old, same old.

**UPDATE:** I have no control over it how is it displayed, I'm just filling in the available properties such as click able, Title, Description etc. And I've tried to add HTML inside Description, but it just outputs everything as a string no matter what code you write.

Comment: When you say "output" do you mean rendered on a web page or actually outputting to a file?

Comment: Something is missing from your description. Can you provide the code that processes the Description property for display?

Comment: So you've updated the question, but you _still_ haven't told us WHICH tooltip library you are using.

Comment: What does `layer.objectAdd` do with your description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a proprietary JavaScript library that you're not allowed/able to edit. You're further not allowed/able to show us the source code of its render function or read it yourself to figure out how it escapes data. Finally, you can't/won't give us the name of this library (assuming it's publicly available) so we can research it ourselves.

You appear to have tried the only reasonable ways that somebody could assume this would work.

The only possible solution is to contact your vendor and demand an answer.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what you're doing with the text, but my guess is you're rendering it as Html.  In that case, you should be using a `<br />` tag instead of a \n.

**EDIT:** It sounds like this doesn't solve your problem, because html tags are encoded and displayed, rather than interepreted as html tags.  In that case, you'll either have to modify your tooltip display library, or go with a different library.

Comment: Just checked how you edited it...now I know something new, too.  Win-win.  :)

Comment: Its a logical answer James, but it isn't the right one I don't see why people are voting up your answer, I mean thank you for your effort but I still didn't get my answer

Comment: Well, they've voted it up because it's the usual solution, and it seemed likely to work.  Unfortunately, it looks like your system, whatever it is, is specifically looking for tags and encoding them so they are displayed, rather than interpreted.  If that is the case, then you may well be out of luck...there may not be a solution short of somehow changing the system you're working with.

Answer (score 6):

What kind of tootips? If it's a JavaScript library that floats divs over the page you would need to change the library to detect the `\n` and insert a line break.

If it's simple `title` attributes, I'm afraid you can't (reliably) have a newline in them at all. Some browsers will render `title="a&#10;b"` (or the JavaScript equivalent `element.title= 'a\nb';`) on two lines; others won't.

Answer (score 3):

Since the tooltip strips html and you cant change that, there aren't a lot of options.

One (rather unpleasant) solution would be to set description to

```
"My Description1 UNIQUE_STRING_TO_REPLACE My Description2"
```

Then you can do a search through the DOM to find the node that contains the substring `UNIQUE_STRING_TO_REPLACE` and replace it with `<br />`

If you look at the html generated, you may be able to limit your searching to make it faster (your tooltips may all share a class or a similar id.) You'd have to check this yourself, since I don't have access to your html.

It is **very** hackish (and not very fast) and it would be preferable for you to have the tool-tip allow you to add new lines, but if nothing else works and you must to get this to work, this will at least accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 2):

You're using some kind of library that implements tooltypes. What is it? You should read the documentation for the tooltip library.

Perhaps you can do `<p>My description1</p><p>My description2</p>` or maybe multipline descriptions are not implemented in the library you are using.

We don't have enough code to know. Maybe show us the list of scripts that's being included in the html.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of tooltip it is, because the gaming company sold us their api and we're working with it(or better) around it.

Comment: Oh OK. It sounds like the library may be stripping out the html internally.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the text displayed in markup, newlines won't work, you have to specify it in HTML (via `<br />` or any combinaison of `<p></p>` or `<div></div>`).

```
Description: "MyDescription1<br/>MyDescription2"
```

Or, even better, you can translate line breaks in HTML line breaks when you render the actual content:

```
document.write(foo.Description.replace('\n','<br/>'));
```

If Description text is meant to be displayed in alert() messages, \n will work. So it's better to make the decision to escape when you render, not in the content of your object.

Comment: How do you actually display it?

Answer (score 2):

Can you add the style `white-space: pre` to your tooltip window (either inline style or in a stylesheet)?

Answer (score 0):

The JS library is escaping your HTML chars and your content is displayed as HTML, so `"\n"` is transformed into a newline but shown as a simple space. so, with the avaiable tools you don't have a way to do it without modifying the library (or maybe reading some more about it).

Answer (score 0):

You might try `\r\n`, or its equivalent, `&#10;&#13;`.  Since this is getting rendered by the browser, that might push a proper Windows newline through to the tooltip.  Completely non-platform-specific, though.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, separate the lines with middle dots (·, U+00B7). Not as readable as proper line breaks, but your best option given the tooltip constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post which tooltip library you are using?

You are not by any chance making the output from within PHP (or another scripting language that swallows lone backslashes)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the backslash with a backslash? Try using `"\\\n"` (that's what Google recommends, but it didn't work for me in an `alert()` call).

I got it to work in `alert()` in Firefox with `" \n"`.