# Jquery and Contenteditable - Forced newlines are shown like a single space

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I found the way to make all browsers prevent the default event when pressing "enter", in order to show a newline "\n". The original code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/FhEf6/3/

It works perfectly, but when I include this on my own site, (with Jquery 1.7.2) it does show the new "\n" like just a single space. I am curious because in the source it shows the newlines correctly.

Other thing is that if I try to replace by `<br>` instead of by newlines... the `<br>` are shown like this, entirely (looking on the source the <,> are replaced by their respective htmlentities...).

It's a quite strange thing, because the original code works perfectly in jsfiddle, and I did not make ANY change. I read a question here ([View Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688086/n-newline-character-wont-work-with-javascript)) but I do not think it's a nice solution.

**Edit**:

Ups!... I need to use "white-space:pre" on the container. Ok, but... I still do not get the sense of it, why does it work in this way?, a new line is a new line, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still HTML so using new line character will not work. Stick with the **<br>** tag.

This isn't working with your current code because it is an **element** node vs. a **textnode**.

I recommend using [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) for all contenteditable projects.

I have an almost working solution here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7A8Xw/ (in chrome it inserts breaks but it's not moving cursor to after br if you hit enter at the end of the content (works if you hit it twice))