# Multi-line output in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So let me just start out by saying that I don't have much experience with Javascript. If someone could give me a basic explanation, that would be great.

Anyways, I want to take a two dimensional matrix and print it on the screen. This is my code so far:

```
function matrixToString(arr) {
returnString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        returnString += Math.round(arr[i][j]*10000)/10000 + ' ';
    }
    returnString += "\n";
}
    return returnString

}
```

So when I call `alert(matrixToString(n))`, it works as expected. However, when I use `document.write(matrixToString(n))`, it basically puts everything on one line and prints that line. The same applies if I put the string into a div and append the div.

I guess my question is basically how do I put multi-line outputs to HTML in javascript.

Comment: `document.write` is outdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your multiline requirement only for presentation purpose? If so, then you just need to add '
' to the end of each line. '\n' does not work when rendering HTML. Instead just replace:

```
returnString += "\n";
```

with

```
returnString += "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` is outdated and hence try directly manipulate DOM.

For example:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = matrixToString(n);
```

Also with reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688100/1671639),

> It depends on what you're doing with the text, but my guess is you're
>   rendering it as Html. In that case, you should be using a `<br />` tag
>   instead of a \n.

so use `returnString += "<br />";` to solve your problem.

Comment: @user2977960 instead of `\n` use `br` tags (`returnString += "</br>";`)

Answer (score 0):

in you code just replce \n with "br"
like this

```
function matrixToString(arr) {
returnString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        returnString += Math.round(arr[i][j]*10000)/10000 + ' ';
    }
    returnString += "<br>";
}
    return returnString

}
```

this works for my case